# How can I use @Delegate in a custom task with Gradle 7?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I've got a custom task (specifically https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/marklogic/gradle/task/MlcpTask.groovy#L26 , though I'm going to provide a bare minimum example below) where I've been using @Delegate on a task property for many versions of Gradle, but it no longer works with Gradle 7. I've tried adding @Input/@Optional everywhere, but no luck.

My use case in the above task is that I want to reuse a Java class that has dozens of properties on it, and I want a user to be able to assign values to those properties via task properties in their build.gradle file.

Here's the easiest way to reproduce the problem I'm having - I add the following to my build.gradle file:

```
class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    @Delegate
    MyBean myBean = new MyBean()

    @TaskAction
    void myAction() {
        println "myBean value: " + myBean.myValue
    }
}

class MyBean {
    String myValue
}

task myTest(type: MyTask) {
    myValue = "something"
}
```

And when I run "myTest" using Gradle 6.9, it runs fine and prints out "myBean value: something". When I run this on Gradle 7.1.1, I get an error of "Type 'MyTask' property 'myBean' is missing an input or output annotation.".

So I added @Input to myBean. Then I get an error of "Type 'MyTask' property 'myValue' is missing an input or output annotation."

So I add @Input to myValue in the MyBean class, and I get the same error of "Type 'MyTask' property 'myValue' is missing an input or output annotation."

Is there a way for @Delegate to still work in this fashion in Gradle, and if so, how? Or is this possibly a bug in Gradle 7? I'll file one if so. Or, is there a better way to do this - i.e. to reuse an existing Java class in a Gradle task such that the task can delegate property assignments to the Java class?

Comment: I don't think so, I may be wrong. Generally, Gradle discourages using language specific features and instead use plain Java or Gradle APIs. Your issue may be due to Gradle's upgrade to Groovy 3 in Gradle 7, but I'm not sure. There are alternative ways for what you're doing which I'll post an answer later.